# WordPress: How To get_the_title() outside loop, into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

OK, so this has to do with tracking.

I have this inside a loop:

```
<a onclick="tracking(); return false;">This Is A Button</a>
```

I have this outside the loop:

```
function tracking() {
    var img = document.createElement( "img" );
    img.setAttribute( "src", "https://example.com?source=" );
    document.body.appendChild( img );
}
```

Every time a person clicks on the button, I want to capture the title of the post, and then append it to the end of the `img.setAttibute`.

So as an example, I envision something like this:

```
img.setAttribute("src", "https://example.com?source="+my-script-var.get_the_title);
```

In my tracking, I want to be able to see the post title, and the end result to look like this:

```
https://example.com?source=TheLoopTitle
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should works:

```
<a onclick="tracking('<?php the_title() ?>'); return false;">This Is A Button</a>

function tracking( title ) {
    var img = document.createElement( "img" );
    img.setAttribute( "src", "https://example.com?source=" + title );
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: And look out when you have title with " ' " (<?php the_title() ?>) maybe some string escape should be run.

Comment: I'm new to javascript. Any idea how I can add that string escape to this existing script?

Comment: Actually, would you consider applying this just above the `var` section?:  `title=title.trim().replace(/ /g, '%20').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');`

Comment: need to escape in php tags to js be always valid, just do in onClick: <?php echo str_replace(["'", '"'], '', get_the_title() ) ?>